# How to arrange two tables in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, built-in-symbols

Consider two tables:

```
tab1 = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 1, 2, 0.1}, {y, 1, 3, 0.5}], {1, 2}];
tab2 = Flatten[
   Table[{p, q}, {p, 0.1, 10, 0.2}, {q, 20, 199, 11}], {1, 2}];
```

I would like to glue it in the form

```
{tab1[[i]][[1]], tab1[[i]][[2]], tab2[[j]][[1]], 
  tab2[[j]][[2]]}
```

where i runs from 1 to Length[tab1] and j from 1 to Length[tab2]. My attempt is a brute force:

```
Table[{tab1[[i]][[1]], tab1[[i]][[2]], tab2[[j]][[1]], 
  tab2[[j]][[2]]}, {i, 1, Length[tab1], 1}, {j, 1, Length[tab2], 1}]
```

But it seems to be extremely slow. Could you please tell me whether some faster way exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aa = Table[{tab1[[i]][[1]], tab1[[i]][[2]], tab2[[j]][[1]], tab2[[j]][[2]]}, 
      {i, 1, Length[tab1], 1}, {j, 1, Length[tab2], 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.146368

You can use `Outer`:

```
bb = Outer[Join, tab1, tab2, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
aa == bb
```

> 0.040488
>
> True

Or, if you have to execute it more often, you can `Compile` the code:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 2}},
   Table[Join[x, Compile`GetElement[y, i]], {i, 1, Length[y]}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Then

```
cc = cf[tab1, tab2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
aa == cc
```

> 0.002277
>
> True

Using `Tuples` and `Reshape` is even better, provided that you turn `tab2` into an array of reals only (and thus into a packed array):

```
tab1 = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 1, 2, 0.1}, {y, 1, 3, 0.5}], {1, 2}];
tab2 = Flatten[Table[{p, q}, {p, 0.1, 10., 0.2}, {q, 20., 199., 11.}], {1, 2}];

dd = ArrayReshape[
     Tuples[{tab1, tab2}],
     {Dimensions[tab1][[1]], Dimensions[tab2][[1]], Dimensions[tab1][[2]] + Dimensions[tab2][[2]]}
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
aa == dd
```

> 0.000416
>
> True

And `Flatten[aa, {1, 2}]` can be obtained like this:

```
ee = ArrayReshape[
     Tuples[{tab1, tab2}],
     {Dimensions[tab1][[1]] Dimensions[tab2][[1]], Dimensions[tab1][[2]] + Dimensions[tab2][[2]]}
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Flatten[aa, {1, 2}] == ee
```

> 0.000413
>
> True